# Regular Expression for matching number only with/without hypenin middle?

Tags: regex

I want regular expression which pass below 2 conditions:

- take digit from 0 to 9. Ex: 123456789
- take digit from 0-9 with hypen in center. Ex. 1234-5678

Comment: How about this `\d+(?:-\d+)?`

Comment: So that't 4 digits followed by 4 digits with an option hyphen between them? Doesn't the regex almost write itself?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read the guide how to ask a question! https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Could you precise about the regex flavor and language used? Plus, after reading your comments, would be a good idea to give us a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

```
\d{4}-?\d{4}
```

Explanation :

`\d{4}` matches 4 digits.

`-?` matches an optional hyphen

`\d{4}` matches another 4 digits.

Edit - if any number of digits are allowed on either side of the hyphen, then try this:

```
\d+-?\d+
```

Comment: text.match(/\d+-?\d+/) , i am using in this way. but when i put 1234-1234, it is not passing this exp.

Comment: @ShubhamSikarwar \d+-?\d+ works for me in several online regex testers. Why the extra '/' characters?